# Pausing a workflow?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, office-365, designer-workflow

I have a 2010 list workflow that sends an email to a distribution list after a list item is created. If one of the fields equals "No" (have you scheduled the meeting for this yet: yes or no?) then I pause the workflow for 24 hours, and send an email (after 24 hours) to the person who created the list to remind them to schedule the meeting in the calendar.

My question is, does pausing this workflow for 24 hours put everything else on hold? Meaning, if someone indicates that they have not scheduled their meeting yet, and the workflow pauses for 24 hours, does that mean if someone else creates a new list item within that 24 hour time period, the original email will not fire upon new item creation in the list?

Comment: In SharePoint 2010 workflow use **Add Time to Date** http://blogs.elon.edu/techgeeks/2013/08/15/sharepoint-designer-pause-workflow-until-a-specific-time/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it does not pause anything else. The workflows work at **item level**, so creating a new item does not affect the activity of other items and vice versa.
Just remember that in case of many workflows active at the same time you can have a negative impact on performance.

Comment: Thanks @Marpio, that's what I was not sure about. If the workflows work at an item level or a list level.